# Better way to save data in database using django serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hello I am working on a project in which I'm making serializers
and I send post requests using postman. This is working fine but this is a very small part of the application and the code will grow to be very large. If there is a better way of doing this in which I write smaller code then I would like to employ that.
Right now the way I'm saving the information is as follows

models.py

```
class Services(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Services
        fields = ('id', 'business', 'service')
```

views.py

```
class ServiceAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data

        business = Business.objects.get(user=request.user)
        data['business'] = business.pk
        serializer = BusinessSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('service/', ServiceAPIView.as_view()),
]
```

****Edited*****

Here is the business model

```
class Business(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    invoices_terms = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)

    website = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    tax_percentage = models.DecimalField(blank=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    labour_rate_per_hour = models.DecimalField(blank=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    tax_hst_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

Comment: You might have wrongly named BusinessAPIView as SeriveAPIView. Can you show your business model too ?

Comment: No I am mentioned the wrong url pattern, I'm gonna update it and also give you the business model. Is there a to do this using ModelViewSet?

Answer (score 2):

Well the code looks ok and it's also ok to have deep modules.

A little update could be the following:

```
class ServiceAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
    serializer_class = ServiceSerializer
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        business = Business.objects.get(user=request.user)
        data['business'] = business.pk
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

In this way you can write only one Response line for each view request method and avoid to use if/else statements